# How to show some WPF User Control as a Modal Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to show some WPF User Control as a Modal Window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put them in a new window shell and call [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) on it.